# How to open a pyqt5 application from another pyqt5 application?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

#### Filename : login.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_login(object):
    key=-1
    def overall_coordinator_clicked(self):
                self.overall_coordinator.setStyleSheet("border-bottom:3px solid red;\n"
"border-top:3px solid red;\n")
                self.coordinator.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.member.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.volunteer.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                key=0
    def coordinator_clicked(self):
                self.overall_coordinator.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.coordinator.setStyleSheet("border-bottom:3px solid red;\n"
"border-top:3px solid red;\n")
                self.member.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.volunteer.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                key=1
    def member_clicked(self):
                self.overall_coordinator.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.coordinator.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.member.setStyleSheet("border-bottom:3px solid red;\n"
"border-top:3px solid red;\n")
                self.volunteer.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                key=2
    def volunteer_clicked(self):
                self.overall_coordinator.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.coordinator.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.member.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid white;")
                self.volunteer.setStyleSheet("border-bottom:3px solid red;\n"
"border-top:3px solid red;\n")
                key=3
    #def login(self):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(923, 606)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(923, 606))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(923, 606))
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:#1A237E;")
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 30, 231, 201))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("border-image:url(\"techfusion_logo.png\");")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.login_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.login_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 480, 200, 41))
        self.login_btn.setStyleSheet(" color:white;\n"
" background-color:#1A237E;\n"
" border-radius:20px;\n"
"font-weight:bold;\n"
"font-size:18px;\n"
"border : 2px solid white;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.login_btn.setObjectName("login_btn")
        #self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.login_password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.login_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 420, 331, 25))
        self.login_password.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid transparent;\n"
"border-bottom:2px solid white;\n"
"color:white;\n"
"background-color:transparent;")
        self.login_password.setText("")
        self.login_password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.login_password.setObjectName("login_password")
        self.login_username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.login_username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 370, 331, 25))
        self.login_username.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid transparent;\n"
"border-bottom:2px solid white;\n"
"background-color:transparent;\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.login_username.setObjectName("login_username")
        self.designation = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralWidget)
        self.designation.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 280, 701, 61))
        self.designation.setStyleSheet("color:white;\n"
"font-weight:bold;\n"
"border:0px solid transparent;")
        self.designation.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.designation.setObjectName("designation")
        self.overall_coordinator = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.designation)
        self.overall_coordinator.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 30, 181, 28))
        self.overall_coordinator.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color:transparent;\n"
"font-weight:normal;\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.overall_coordinator.setObjectName("overall_coordinator")
#######overall_coordinator selected######
        self.overall_coordinator.clicked.connect(self.overall_coordinator_clicked)
#########################################
        self.coordinator = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.designation)
        self.coordinator.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 181, 28))
        self.coordinator.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color:transparent;\n"
"font-weight:normal;\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.coordinator.setObjectName("coordinator")
#######overall_coordinator selected######
        self.coordinator.clicked.connect(self.coordinator_clicked)
#########################################
        self.member = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.designation)
        self.member.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 30, 181, 28))
        self.member.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color:transparent;\n"
"font-weight:normal;\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.member.setObjectName("member")
#######overall_coordinator selected######
        self.member.clicked.connect(self.member_clicked)
#########################################
        self.volunteer = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.designation)
        self.volunteer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 30, 181, 28))
        self.volunteer.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color:transparent;\n"
"font-weight:normal;\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.volunteer.setObjectName("volunteer")
#######overall_coordinator selected######
        self.volunteer.clicked.connect(self.volunteer_clicked)
#########################################
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 923, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Voyage"))
        self.login_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LOGIN"))
        self.login_username.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Username"))
        self.login_password.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password"))
        self.designation.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "LOGIN AS"))
        self.overall_coordinator.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Overall Coordinator"))
        self.coordinator.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Coordinator"))
        self.member.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Member"))
        self.volunteer.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Volunteer"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_login()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### Filename : dashboard.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from login import Ui_login


class Ui_dashboard(object):
    #def member(self):
    #def team(self):
    #def log_out(self):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(923, 606)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(923, 606))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(923, 606))
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:#1A237E;")
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 40, 231, 201))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("border-image:url(\"techfusion_logo.png\");")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.member = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.member.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 320, 200, 41))
        self.member.setStyleSheet(" color:white;\n"
" background-color:#1A237E;\n"
" border-radius:20px;\n"
"border : 2px solid white;\n"
"font-weight:bold;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.member.setObjectName("member")
        self.team = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.team.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 400, 200, 41))
        self.team.setStyleSheet(" color:white;\n"
" background-color:#1A237E;\n"
" border-radius:20px;\n"
"font-weight:bold;\n"
"border : 2px solid white;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.team.setObjectName("team")
        self.logout = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.logout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 10, 89, 25))
        self.logout.setStyleSheet(" color:white;\n"
                                  " background-color:#1A237E;\n"
                                  " border-radius:20px;\n"
                                  "font-weight:bold;\n"
                                  "text-decoration:underline;\n"
                                  "font-size:15px;\n"
                                  "\n"
                                  "")
        self.logout.setObjectName("logout")
        #self.logout.clicked.connect(self.log_out)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 923, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Voyage"))
        self.member.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MEMBER"))
        self.team.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TEAM"))
        self.logout.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LOGOUT"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_dashboard()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There is QPushButton named "logout" in dashboard.py . What I want is that when I click logout button, The dashboard.py exits and login.py opens up. What code should I use in order to achieve this. I am stuck on this since past 2 days. Gone through many webpages but I wasn't able to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you showed what you have tried so far, instead of saying "I have tried a lot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to modify the design generated by Qt Designer, it is appropriate to create a class that manages the design and implement the logic. As your goal is to close the current window and open another window by pressing the button, then we must use the clicked signal of the button and connect them to both tasks as shown below:

```
.
├── dashboard.py
├── login.py
└── main.py
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from login import Ui_login
from dashboard import Ui_dashboard


class Login(QMainWindow, Ui_login):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Dashboard(QMainWindow, Ui_dashboard):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.logout.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dashboard()
    l = Login()
    w.logout.clicked.connect(l.show)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```